# Server required for a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, hosting

Suppose my Facebook application is just one or two pages which makes use of the facebook API (doing stuff with the user's detais). Is it essential that I have my own server for something this simple?

I keep reading about things like 'Social Plugins'. Is there a better option than creating a canvas page on my own server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. You can use a webhosting and use your own domain to host your Facebook fanpage. Do remember that from 2011-10-01, it's essential that your domain should have SSL enabled in order to use your own hosting.

Alternately you can use [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) as a free alternative option. Since Dropbox has an SSL feature enabled, you can simply create an dropbox account and hosting everything on Dropbox and then iframe it using the Facebook application.

1. Alternately you can use an solution like in *[Getting Started with Your Facebook Application on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook)*.

Further, if you are creating things on your own hosting, you can follow the 
article *[Tutorial: Add an iFrame Application to your Facebook Fan Page – Fall 2011](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-fall-2012/)*.

Comment: +1 Great answer!  Can you give a little bit more detail on the DropBox hosting option?

Comment: For dropbox hosting this is what you can do, 

1) Go to http://www.dropbox.com and create a free Account.
2) Upload your files in the account. (Make sure you update your link images accordingly if you are using them)
3) Now add the link where you uploaded to facebook developers app which you created and your page should be live.

Comment: So basically I'll be limited to client-side technologies for the application logic... Interesting idea... Useful for v.small projects ( like the one the OP has detailed ).

Comment: If you are looking for a small project then you can use dropbox or free app solution as I mentioned in my post. This way you won't have to bare any kind of cost.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to create a page that other users can use, then you can start by using regular webhosting and placing your application on that. An own server seems a bit overkill for that. In time you can still scale your app if necessary and evolve to an own server.