# Hosting Facebook apps on Dropbox

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, dropbox

I'm trying to host a simple JS based Facebook app on dropbox following this question:
[Server required for a Facebook application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113990/server-required-for-a-facebook-application)

Currently I just want to get the login part done before I can continue but i'm having some issues - apparently the call for ***FB.getLoginStatus*** doesn't return so the actual **login** function isn't called. 
If I call login() directly (currently commented out) I manage to log into Facebook but then the call ***FB.api('/me', function(response) {...})*** doesn't return so I'm logged in but can't really do anything.
What am I missing? I've set the correct URLs in my Facebook's app page and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, why does it have to be so hard? :/

Here is my JS code (pretty much copy+paste from Facebook login tutorial) and the HTML is exactly copy+paste from that tutorial.

```
    // Additional JS functions here
        function testAPI() {
            document.write('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... </br>');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                document.write('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.</br');
            });
        }
        function login() {
            document.write('Logging to Facebook </br>');
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // connected
                    document.write("User now connected </br>");
                    testAPI();
                } else {
                    // cancelled
                    document.write("User cancelled </br>");
                }
            });
        }
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            document.write("Connecting to facebook </br>");
            FB.init({
              appId      : '542474505763387', // App ID
              channelUrl : 'https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/index.html?w=71a3a216', // Channel File
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
            //login();

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                document.write("Response </br>");
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    document.write("connected </br>");
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // not_authorized
                    document.write("not_authorized </br>");
                    login();
                } else {
                    // not_logged_in
                    document.write("not_logged_in </br>");
                    login();
                }
            });

        };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    </script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that dropbox will lock the page after some number of requests. It's not a hosting.

Comment: try calling testapi() on click of a button or link.